# Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed reason? 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code to populate my combobox (Question_Num) using a defined name. My defined name is stored in `str3`. I'm very new to VBA. When I run the program it gives run time error

> method range of object _worksheet failed

I don't know what I am doing wrong

this is where the program hangs...`Set rngPage = ws.Range(str3)`

```
Private Sub loadPage()

   Dim rngPage As Range
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3 As String

      Set ws = Worksheets(Year_Combine.Value)
      Sheets(Year_Combine.Value).Activate

      str1 = Left(Year_Combine.Value, 4)
      str2 = Right(Year_Combine.Value, 1)
      str3 = "PageNum_" & str1 & "_" & str2

      Set rngPage = ws.Range(str3)

       For Each rngPage In ws.Range(str3)
            Me.Question_Num.AddItem rngPage.Value
       Next rngPage

End Sub
```

Comment: `Year_Combine` is a not declared variable. • I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. And declare all variable properly. • Reading [mcve] might help to improve your question.

Comment: What is `Year_Combine` ?

Comment: Is `Year_Combine` some public variable? And the main - which line gives error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not giving a valid range.

The **Range** method receives a range of **Cells** as an argument, for example, "A1" if you are referring to the first cell in a worksheet, or "A1:B1" if you want to refer to the first 2 horizontal cells.

You can check the following link for more information on how to use the **.Range** method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)

Comment: Thanks @mdelapena..you have pointed me in the right direction..It was as a result of an invalid range and I have corrected that. now its working fine..thanks to all

Comment: no problem, mark as the answer would be appreciated.